Oracle 11, Truncate a date, add 1 day, then add time in format hh:mm
I have a date variable that stores a date time, e.g. 17/05/2024 13:46:23
I have another varchar variable that stores a time, e.g '15:21'
I want to take the first variable, truncate it, add 1 day to it, then add the time that is stored in format 'hh:mm'
So for the example above I want to populate a variable with
trunc('17/05/2024 13:46:23') + 1 day + '15:21'
Giving a result of '18/05/2024 15:21'

You first need to trunc and add 1 day to your date field, then convert it to char and concatenate the time and then convert it to date. You probably need to modify the following, but as an example you can try:
select to_date( to_char(trunc(sysdate +1 ), 'DD.MM.YYYY' )||'15:21', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') from dual;


You can use:
DECLARE
  v_input  DATE        := TIMESTAMP '2024-05-17 13:46:32';
  v_time   VARCHAR2(5) := '15:21';
  v_output DATE;
BEGIN
  v_output := TRUNC(v_input)
              + INTERVAL '1' DAY
              + (TO_DATE(v_time, 'HH24:MI') - TO_DATE('00:00', 'HH24:MI'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_output);
END;
/

Which outputs:

2024-05-18 15:21:00


fiddle

2024-05-17 13:46:23 is correct (second part)

Or use INTERVAL data type:
with data(dat, hours) as (
    select to_date('17/05/2024 13:46:23', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '15:21' from dual
)
select dat + TO_DSINTERVAL(inter) from (
    select dat, '1 ' || hours || ':00' as inter from data
);


Here is the step by step:

Remove the time from date

select substr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', 1, instr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', ' ') -1)
from dual


Add one day

select to_date(substr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', 1, instr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', ' ') -1), 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1
from dual


Add the time and format it

select to_char(((to_date(substr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', 1, instr('17/05/2024 13:46:23', ' ') -1), 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1) + interval '15:21' hour to minute),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
from dual

The output varchar will be:

18/05/2024 15:21



Like MT0, but by tiny summarization:
DECLARE
  v_input  DATE        := to_date('2024-05-17 13:46:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
  v_time   VARCHAR2(5) := '15:21';
  v_output DATE;
BEGIN
  v_output := TRUNC(v_input) 
              + 1                    -- equvalent INTERVAL '1' DAY
              + (TO_DATE(v_time, 'HH24:MI') - TO_DATE('00:00', 'HH24:MI'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_output);
END;

But be careful: do it in pl/sql like me and MT0, and avoid using sql(select) like cengiz sevimli, because of performance
